# How to move to prev/next element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say we have a list of integers:

```
var fibonacci = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21];
```

I want to be able to get the next and previous element (just to move the element pointer, without modifying the array) in following manner (example, might go without prototype to redefine the Array interface but why not):

```
fibonacci.prev(); // returns false
fibonacci.next(); // returns 1
fibonacci.next(); // returns 1
fibonacci.next(); // returns 2
fibonacci.next(); // returns 3
fibonacci.next(); // returns 5
fibonacci.next(); // returns 8

fibonacci.prev(); // returns 5

fibonacci.next(); // returns 8
fibonacci.next(); // returns 13
fibonacci.next(); // returns false
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No, its an online playlist with song ids. You might guess this by both my rating and answers that I don't do homework on SO.

Comment: You know, people are so eager to get reputation (me included) that we should probably be grateful when we get homework questions (unlike this question). Does Homework.stackexchange.com exist yet? It should.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to keep the list as an `Array`, you'll have to change its `[[prototype]]` to make it look like an iterable collection:

```
Array.prototype.next = function() {
    return this[++this.current];
};
Array.prototype.prev = function() {
    return this[--this.current];
};
Array.prototype.current = 0;
```

Now every `Array` will have the methods `prev` and `next`, and the `current` property, which points to the "current" elements. A caveat: the `current` property can be modified, thus leading to impredictable results.

Post scriptum: I don't recommend to make `prev` and `next` return `false` when the index is out of range. If you really want to, you can change the methods to something like:

```
Array.prototype.next = function() {
    if (!((this.current + 1) in this)) return false;
    return this[++this.current];
};
```

**UPDATE mid-2016**

I'm updating this answer because it seems it's still receiving views and votes. I should have clarified that the given answer is *a proof of concept* and in general *extending the prototype of native classes is a bad practice*, and should be avoided in production projects.

In particular, it's not much because it's going to mess with `for...in` cycles - which should always be avoided for arrays and it's *definitely* a bad practice for iterating through their elements - and also because since IE9 we can reliably do this instead:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "next", {
    value: function() { return this[++this.current]; },
    enumerable: false
});
```

The main problem is that extending native classes *is not future-proof*, i.e. it may happen that ECMA will introduce a `next` method for arrays that will probably be incompatible with your implementation. It already happened even with very common JS frameworks - the last case was [MooTools' `contains` array extension](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/having-a-non-enumerable-array-prototype-contains-may-not-be-web-compatible) which led [ECMA to change the name to `includes`](http://www.2ality.com/2016/02/array-prototype-includes.html) (bad move, IMO, since we already have `contains` in [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) objects like `Element.classList`).

That being said, it's not that you *must* not extend native prototypes, but you should be aware of what you're doing. The first advice I can give you is to choose names that won't clash with future standard extensions, e.g. `myCompanyNext` instead of just `next`. This will cost you some code elegance but will make you sleep sound.

Even better, in this case you can effectively extend the `Array` class:

```
function MyTraversableArray() {
    if (typeof arguments[0] === "number")
        this.length = arguments[0];
    else this.push.apply(this, arguments);

    this.current = 0;
}
MyTraversableArray.prototype = [];
MyTraversableArray.prototype.constructor = MyTraversableArray;
MyTraversableArray.prototype.next = function() {
    return this[++this.current];
};
MyTraversableArray.prototype.prev = function() {
    return this[--this.current];
};
```

In ES6, moreover, it's easier to extend native classes:

```
class MyTraversableArray extends Array {
    next() {
        return this[++this.current];
    }
}
```

Alas, transpilers have [a hard time with native class extensions](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T1424), and Babel removed its support. But it's because they can't *exactly* replicate some behaviours which have no influence in our case, so you can stick with the above old ES3 code.

Comment: Why wouldn't you return false when out of bounds? For example this is how it's implemented in PHP. There is some inconvinience if an element of the array is actually "false", but besides that?

Comment: @Veseliq PHP, exactly. That's how PHP commonly behaves. But Javascript is different, and for other iterable collections the `next` method usually returns `null` (not even `undefined` like here, but it can be good).

Comment: BTW, there is a simpler way to check for out of bounds - in .prev() `if (this.current-1 < 0) return false;` or `if (this.current===0) return false;` in .next() `if (this.current >= this.length) return false;` because I think your solution solves this with iterations

Comment: @Veseliq That depends on how you want it to behave. If you create an array as `a = new Array(5)`, you'll have `a.length === 5` but `0 in a === false`. `map` and `forEach` don't call the callback function if the element isn't explicitly defined. Use the behaviour that you like.

Comment: such a great snippet :)

Answer (score 26):

I generally recommend against adding things to `Array.prototype` because of the amount of really bad JavaScript out there. For instance, if you set `Array.protoype.next = function () {}` and someone has the following code, then there's a problem:

```
var total = 0, i, myArr = [0,1,2];
for(i in myArr) {
    total += myArr[i];
}
total; //is probably "3next"
```

This bad use of `for-in` loops is disturbingly common out there. So you're asking for trouble by adding to `Array`'s prototype. However, it's pretty easy to build a wrapper to do what you're looking to do:

```
var iterifyArr = function (arr) {
    var cur = 0;
    arr.next = (function () { return (++cur >= this.length) ? false : this[cur]; });
    arr.prev = (function () { return (--cur < 0) ? false : this[cur]; });
    return arr;
};

var fibonacci = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13];
iterifyArr(fibonacci);

fibonacci.prev(); // returns false
fibonacci.next(); // returns 1
fibonacci.next(); // returns 1
fibonacci.next(); // returns 2
fibonacci.next(); // returns 3
fibonacci.next(); // returns 5
fibonacci.next(); // returns 8
fibonacci.prev(); // returns 5
fibonacci.next(); // returns 8
fibonacci.next(); // returns 13
fibonacci.next(); // returns false
```

A couple notes:

First of all, you probably want to have it return `undefined` instead of `false` if you go past the end. Secondly, because this method hides `cur` using a closure, you don't have access to it on your array. So you might want to have a `cur()` method to grab the current value:

```
//Inside the iterifyArr function:
    //...
    arr.cur = (function () { return this[cur]; });
    //...
```

Finally, your requirements are unclear on how far past the end the "pointer" is maintained. Take the following code for example (assuming `fibonacci` is set as above):

```
fibonacci.prev(); //false
fibonacci.prev(); //false
fibonacci.next(); //Should this be false or 1?
```

In my code, it would be `false`, but you might want it to be `1`, in which case you'd have to make a couple simple changes to my code.

Oh, and because it the function returns `arr`, you can "iterify" an array on the same line as you define it, like so:

```
var fibonacci = iterifyArr([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]);
```

That might make things a bit cleaner for you. You can also reset the iterator by re-calling `iterifyArr` on your array, or you could write a method to reset it pretty easily (just set `cur` to 0).

Comment: For some reason I had to change `this` to `arr`. It was working before, not sure if it's because of Webpack, but if you get undefined/alphabet functions for all `this.` or `this[]` occurrences, just use the variable `arr` that is set in the above 'iterifyArr' example. This is definitely the best method I've found so far.

Comment: @Pete may u make tutorial on it ! .One vote to your answer by me.

Answer (score 7):

The **next** aspect of this is now built into arrays, because as of ES2015, arrays are *iterables*, which means you can get an iterator for them which has a `next` method (but keep reading for the "prev" part):

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const iter = a[Symbol.iterator]();
let result;
while (!(result = iter.next()).done) {
  console.log(result.value);
}
```

Iterators only go forward though, not both ways. And of course, you normally don't use an iterator explicitly, you normally use it as part of some iteration construct, such as `for-of`:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (const value of a) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

You can easily give yourself a two-way iterator:

1. By making a standalone function that accepts the array and returns the iterator, or
2. By subclassing `Array` and overriding the iterator in the subclass, or
3. By replacing the default `Array` iterator with your own (just make sure it works exactly like the default one when going forward!)

Here's an example with a subclass:

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
  // Define the iterator function for this class
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    // `index` points at the next value we'll return
    let index = 0;
    // Return the iterator
    return {
      // `next` returns the next
      next: () => {
        const done = index >= this.length;
        const value = done ? undefined : this[index++];
        return { value, done };
      },
      // `prev` returns the previous
      prev: () => {
        const done = index == 0;
        const value = done ? undefined : this[--index];
        return { value, done };
      }
    };
  }
}

// Demonstrate usage:
const a = new MyArray("a", "b");
const i = a[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log("next", JSON.stringify(i.next()));
console.log("next", JSON.stringify(i.next()));
console.log("next", JSON.stringify(i.next()));
console.log("prev", JSON.stringify(i.prev()));
console.log("prev", JSON.stringify(i.prev()));
console.log("prev", JSON.stringify(i.prev()));
console.log("next", JSON.stringify(i.next()));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ES6 provides us with generator functions which can allow us to print out an array quite simply like below

```
function* data() {
  yield* [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21];
}

var fibonnacci = data();

fibonnacci.next()
> {value: 1, done: false}

fibonnacci.next()
> {value: 1, done: false}

fibonnacci.next()
> {value: 2, done: false}

fibonnacci.next()
> {value: 3, done: false}

fibonnacci.next()
> {value: 5, done: false}

fibonnacci.next()
> {value: 8, done: false}

fibonnacci.next()
> {value: 13, done: false}

fibonnacci.next()
> {value: 21, done: false}

fibonnacci.next()
> {value: undefined, done: true}
```

However, an example program does exist on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) which can help print the fibonnacci series upto the element we like to.

```
function* fibonacci() {
  var fn1 = 0;
  var fn2 = 1;
  while (true) {  
    var current = fn1;
    fn1 = fn2;
    fn2 = current + fn1;
    var reset = yield current;
    if (reset) {
        fn1 = 0;
        fn2 = 1;
    }
  }
}

var sequence = fibonacci();
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 0
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 2
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 3
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 5
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 8
console.log(sequence.next(true).value); // 0
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Safer than modifying the native object's prototype is creating a factory function for additional needed array functions:

```
const moreArrayFunctions = arr => ({
    current: 0,
    arr,
    next(){

        if( this.current >= ( this.arr.length - 1 ) ){
             this.current = this.arr.length - 1;
        }else{
            this.current++;
        }

        return this.arr[this.current];
    },
    prev(){

        if( this.current <= 0 ){
            this.current = 0;
        }else{
            this.current--;
        }

        return this.arr[this.current];
    }
});

const fibonacci = moreArrayFunctions([1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]);

fibonacci.next();
fibonacci.prev();
fibonacci.current
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can use an array iterator.

```
var fibonacci = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21];

const fibIterator = fibonacci[Symbol.iterator]()

fibIterator.next(); // {value: 1, done: false}
fibIterator.next(); // {value: 1, done: false}
fibIterator.next(); // {value: 3, done: false}
....
....
fibIterator.next(); // {value: 21, done: false}
fibIterator.next(); // {value: undefined, done: true}
```