# How to move to prev/next index key of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In this Post [How to move to prev/next element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390626/how-to-move-to-prev-next-element-of-an-array) its telling how to move prev/next a array ellement.

But i want the same concept for Prev/Next Array Element Key.

Ex:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[2] = 'hi';
arr[3] = 'hello';
arr[4] = 'how are you';
arr[12] = 'i am fine';

arr.next(3); // returns 4
arr.next(4); // returns 12
arr.next(2); // returns 3
arr.next(12); // returns 2
arr.prev(2); // returns 12
```

Comment: there are no associative arrays in javascript...arrays have index not key. I don't think you realize that array shown has `length=13` . Please explain use in more detail

Comment: Clarifying charlietf.  When you create arr[2], arr[0], and arr[1] are implicitly created.

Comment: Pass an argument: `...prototype.next = function (x) {...}`, and set `this.current = x`. In real life you've also to check the `x` really is given etc.

Comment: Thanks friends for this quick reply. its works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[2] = 'due';
arr[3] = 'hello';
arr[4] = 'quattro';
arr[12] = 'i am fine';

Array.prototype.next = function(n,_k){
    if(typeof this !== "object") return false;
    _k = n;
    n = (typeof n === "undefined" || n+1 == this.length) ? 0 : n + 1;
    for(n; this.length > n+1; n++){
        if(typeof this[n] !== "undefined") return this[n]; // return element value if you want only index use "return n" ... this is for all return
    }
    for(n = 0;n == _k; n++){
        if(typeof this[n] !== "undefined") return this[n];
    }
    return false;
}

Array.prototype.prev = function(n,_k){
    if(typeof this !== "object") return false;
    _k = n;
    n = (typeof n === "undefined" || n == 0) ? this.length : n-1;
    for(n; n > 0; n--){
        if(typeof this[n] !== "undefined") return this[n];
    }
    for(n = 0;n == _k; n--){
        if(typeof this[n] !== "undefined") return this[n];
    }
    return false;
}

var el = arr.next(12);
var el2 = arr.prev(12);

console.log(el);
console.log(el2);
```

in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tdg27/)

Comment: This Returns the Element Value i need it to be return the Element Key. But still thanks for your time.

Comment: hi, :) it's pleasure... so... see the comment... for return the key you only need to change the lines with:
`if(typeof this[n] !== "undefined") return this[n];` into `if(typeof this[n] !== "undefined") return n;` - `this[n];` is the array element value... `n` is the key of the element value.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a plunker to go with the answer: http://plnkr.co/edit/x6stJnXzWzwY197csTHB?p=preview

If you have an array of items.  The first element is always in the `0` position and the last element is in the `array.length-1` position.  Adding an element to an array is as simple as

```
arr.push("January");
```

Lets say you have a bunch of stuff in an array and you want to cycle through it by fixed amounts.  Not necessarily 1, maybe 4. You also want to come back around when you pass the end of the array.

The first issue is that the array is a fixed length and your number to cycle (offset) might exceed the length of the array.

The solution is to use the modulus operator `%` which returns remainder after division.

This means that `((current)+offset)%lengthOfArray` will return the correct position.

```
Array.prototype.move = function(i) {
  this.current = (this.current + i) % this.length;
  return this[this.current];
};
```

The answer marked as correct on the question you referenced has a big flaw in it.

```
Array.prototype.current = 0;
```

means that all arrays will share the same value for current.  It would be better to declare the array like this:

```
var arr = []; //Creates an array
arr.current = 0;
```

Full source code:

```
Array.prototype.move = function(i) {
  this.current = (this.current + i) % this.length;
  return this[this.current];
};


var arr = []; //Creates an array
arr.current = 0; // Better than overriding array constructor 


arr.push("January");
arr.push("February");
arr.push("March");
arr.push("April");
arr.push("May");
arr.push("June");
arr.push("July");
arr.push("August");
arr.push("September");
arr.push("October");
arr.push("November");
arr.push("December");


console.log(arr.move(1));
console.log(arr.move(1));
console.log(arr.move(1));
console.log(arr.move(1));
console.log(arr.move(4));
console.log(arr.move(12));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the other SO answer, here is some basic functions which do what you want :

```
Array.prototype.next = function(i) {
    do {
       if (this[++i] != undefined) {
           return i;
       }
    } while (i < this.length);
    return null;
};
Array.prototype.prev = function(i) {
    do {
       if (this[--i] != undefined) {
           return i;
       }
    } while (i > 0);
    return null;
};
```

Indexes implicitely created have a value of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   const calcIndex = (max, diff) => {
     const limit = max + 1;
     return (limit + diff) % limit;
   }
```

allows you to move in bound of 0...n with positive or negative difference. For example

if we need to go through 0...4:

```
calcIndex(4, 0) => 0
calcIndex(4, 1) => 1
calcIndex(4, 2) => 2
calcIndex(4, 3) => 3
calcIndex(4, 4) => 4
calcIndex(4, 5) => 0
calcIndex(4, 6) => 1
calcIndex(4, -1) => 4
calcIndex(4, -2) => 3
```