# How to move to prev/next element of an array, reset index

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have modify the code from the link below

[How to move to prev/next element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390626/how-to-move-to-prev-next-element-of-an-array)

i like the second answer and understand the code, but i'm a beginner and i cannot work out how to reset the index so that every time it calls this function it cycles through the array. the poster said something about using a method to set the iterator to 0. could someone show me what the correct syntax should be. i would provide what i have done, but my sample code cannot be accepted. thanks

thanks for your responses, i now understand what he meant by reset, but this is not what i wanted. i wanted to create a function that if i used a key it would move the array pointer and read me the item. if the pointer reached the end of the array it was meant to return to the beginning

i modified one of the methods which is below, which is meant to set the iterator to 0 instead of returning false.

arr.next = (function () { return (++cur < this.length) ?this[cur] : cur=-1; });

when i use this function it will cycle through the array, but between the end and the beginning it will return -1. is it possible to stop this from happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "it cannot be accepted"?? Are you not able to post it here for some reason?

Comment: Did you put your code in a code block? If it contains HTML, SO strips it from question/answer bodies unless it's in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Just calling the function `iterifyArr(fibonacci);` again resets it:

```
var iterifyArr = function (arr) {
    var cur = 0;
    arr.next = (function () { return (++cur >= this.length) ? false : this[cur]; });
    arr.prev = (function () { return (--cur < 0) ? false : this[cur]; });
    return arr;
};

var fibonacci = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13];
iterifyArr(fibonacci);

console.log(fibonacci.next())//1
console.log(fibonacci.next())//2
console.log(fibonacci.next())//3
console.log(fibonacci.next())//5
iterifyArr(fibonacci);
console.log(fibonacci.next())//1
console.log(fibonacci.next())//2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `reset` method to `iterifyArr`.

```
var iterifyArr = function (arr) {
    var cur = 0;
    arr.next = (function () { return (++cur >= this.length) ? false : this[cur]; });
    arr.prev = (function () { return (--cur < 0) ? false : this[cur]; });
    arr.reset = (function () { cur = 0; });
    return arr;
};
```

http://jsbin.com/naduwoju/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Just add a reset function to an Array:

```
Array.prototype.next = function() {
    if (!((this.current + 1) in this)) return false;
    return this[++this.current];
};

Array.prototype.prev = function() {
    if (!((this.current - 1) in this)) return false;
    return this[-this.current];
};

Array.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.current = 0;
    return true;
};

var fibonacci = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21];
fibonacci.reset(); // init current to 0. use reset where ever you want
fibonacci.prev(); // returns false
fibonacci.next(); // returns 1
fibonacci.next(); // returns 1
fibonacci.next(); // returns 2
fibonacci.next(); // returns 3
fibonacci.next(); // returns 5
fibonacci.next(); // returns 8

fibonacci.prev(); // returns 5

fibonacci.next(); // returns 8
fibonacci.next(); // returns 13
fibonacci.next(); // returns false

fibonacci.reset();
fibonacci.next(); // returns 1
```