# javascript what is the equivalent of current and next function in php?

Tags: javascript

i want to get the current item in Javascript and after processing in it move the array pointer
just like php functions `current()` & `next()`

something like

```
array.current()
array.next()
```

any help ?

Comment: [ -> This answer might help you.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390626/how-to-move-to-prev-next-element-of-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make prototype function. E.g.

```
    Array.prototype.cursorPosition = 0;
     Array.prototype.current = function(){
         return this[this.cursorPosition];
     }
     Array.prototype.next = function(){
          this.cursorPosition=this.cursorPosition+1;
         return this[this.cursorPosition];

     }
     Array.prototype.previous = function(){
          this.cursorPosition=this.cursorPosition-1;
         return this[this.cursorPosition];

     }

   // implementation
      var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
       alert(fruits.current())   ;
       alert(fruits.next()) ;
       alert(fruits.previous()) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i in myArray){
  doSomething();
}
```

[There's a good read here on different ways to iterate through arrays in Javascript](http://www.sebarmeli.com/blog/2010/12/06/best-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/).

Comment: It is actually more efficient and wiser to use a vanilla for-loop. i.e. `for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { var item = array[i]; }`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl it's only wiser if the order is specifically important. I'll add an info link.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is one you ll have to make a function yourself.
Something like

```
function nextItem(num) { 
  return p[($.inArray(num, p) + 1) % p.length]; 
}
```

but I don't get why you would want something like this when you could just iterate through the array.

Answer (score 0):

Although not polished, this would give a good start.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

Array.prototype.currentIndex = -1;

Array.prototype.next = function(){
  if(this.currentIndex + 1 < this.length){
    this.currentIndex += 1;
    return this[this.currentIndex];  
  }else{
    return;
  }
};

Array.prototype.current = function(){  
    return this[this.currentIndex];
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cazoyuvo/1/edit)